# Find the probability of $\{a\}$,$\{b\}$ and $\{c\}$ with $P(\{a,b\})=0.7$ and $P(\{b,c\})=0.6$, why are these events mutually exclusive?

Tags: probability

My professor solved it by doing

$$P(\{a\})+P(\{b\})+P(\{c\}) = 1 \\
P(\{a,b\}) = P(\{a\})+P(\{b\}) = 0.7 \\
P(\{b,c\}) = P(\{b\})+P(\{c\}) = 0.6 \\
P(\{c\}) = 1-P(\{a\})-P(\{b\}) = 1 - 0.7 = 0.3$$

And so on. I could continue from here, my question is, why did he assume that these events are mutually exclusive (I understand that you use these formulas like this when they are)?

Comment: Your professor is assuming that $a,b,c$ are all the distinct possible results of a random process. It depends on the language used in the original problem, whether that this is a valid assumption, or if your professor did not carefully word the question to warrant this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a matter of context. It may be that the events were said (verbally or otherwise) to be mutually exclusive -- or perhaps it's a matter of notation in your class that something like $\{a\}$ denotes an atom (i.e. a single element, rather than a set of multiple elements) in the sample space. (Note: This notational convention is fairly common, if perhaps not quite universal.)

EDIT: As paw88789 points out, the solution implies that there are no *other* singletons, which is certainly not clear from the snippet you have provided. Such a stipulation would need to be made explicit in the problem.

Comment: If $a, b, c$ are indeed atoms, then they are (essentially) all the atoms, as the first line of the given data shows: $P(\{a\}) + P(\{b\}) + P(\{c\})  = 1$

Comment: @Arthur Right -- I was trying to get at that with my final paragraph. That looked to me like part of the *solution*, rather than the *problem text* (which I assumed to have been enclosed in the title of the post), but I may have misinterpreted.

Comment: Yes, now that you say it, you're right. That does look like part of the solution.

Comment: I do remember vaguely my professor saying that the other professor didn't give enough information in this problem but solved this this way so he assumed... etc... something like that. You are probably right. Could this be solved if they weren't mutually exclusive?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like $a,b,c$ are outcomes (individual elements of the sample space).  So events $\{a\}$, $\{b\}$ and $\{c\}$ are, in fact, disjoint.  What is not clear, but implied in the solution you present, is that there are no other outcomes. (I.e., the entire sample space is $\{a,b,c\}$.)