# Does $P(\{ a, b \})$ mean the union or the intersection of these sets?

Tags: probability

From [Find the probability of $\{a\}$,$\{b\}$ and $\{c\}$ with $P(\{a,b\})=0.7$ and $P(\{b,c\})=0.6$, why are these events mutually exclusive?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3535709/find-the-probability-of-a-b-and-c-with-p-a-b-0-7-and-p)

My professor used the linear system shown in the post in that link. I thought that this notation meant "the probability of $\{ a \}$ and then $\{ b \}$" which would be calculated using $P(\{ a \} ) * P (\{ b \} )$ (since these events are independent).

Am I missing something here? Doesn't adding them find "the probability of {a} *or* {b}" instead?

Comment: @ε--δ Yes, sorry

Answer (score 1):

$P(\{a,b\})$ is simply the probabilty on the event $\{a,b\}$. Since we can write $\{a,b\} = \{a\} \cup \{b\}$, we have a union here, and not an intersection. Thus, the correct interpretation here is "OR" and not "AND".

Note also that $$P(\{a,b\}) = P(\{a\} \cup \{b\}) = P(\{a\}) + P(\{b\})$$

by additivity of probability measure (implicitely assuming that $a \ne b)$.